# Python Cplex Constraint Programming Logical Constraint

Tags: python, cplex, constraint-programming

I am studying Cplex CP in Python, and I have two integer variables x and y.

I do some calculations and I find x's value, for example:

y = ..some calculations..

x = 3600 / y

I want to do this, If the x is lower than the 200(limit of x), x is 3600 / y. But, If the x is higher than the 200, x is 200.

I tried these expressions:

1:

```
((x >= limit_x) == limit_x ) or ((x <= limit_x) == 3600 / y )
```

1.revised:

```
((x >= limit_x) == limit_x ) and ((x <= limit_x) == 3600 / y )
```

2:

```
x == 3600 / y
x <= limit_x
```

3:

```
(x <= limit_x) == 3600 / y
```

I couldn't find any solution. I need your bits of help.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me [mix](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoodisjonctioncpo.py)

[disjuntion](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoodisjunction.py) and [Constraint Programming](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoocpo.py)

And I get

```
from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel

mdl = CpoModel(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(0,1000,name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(0,1000,name='nbBus30')
mdl.add(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300)

mdl.add(1==mdl.logical_or(nbbus40>=7,nbbus40<=3))
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

msol=mdl.solve()

print(msol[nbbus40]," buses 40 seats")
print(msol[nbbus30]," buses 30 seats")
```

that gives

```
3  buses 40 seats
6  buses 30 seats
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mr. Fleischer. I saw this example from your LinkedIn account, but I have some problems here. 

The value of x could be 0 or 3600 / y or the limit of x.  Can I use the nested logical or?

Comment: Sure. In my tiny example I can write mdl.add(1==mdl.logical_or(nbbus40>=10,mdl.logical_or(nbbus40==2,nbbus40==1)))